# How to get a custom made response on a request timed out

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I'm not able to get my custom 503 response when a request is timed out. I am using the $http service and the timeout config is a promise. This is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7igxU2tC2WDWeYewRZXd?p=info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a promise to the $http object, if it resolves before the request is able to resolve, the response is ABORTED which literally has:

- Status of "0"
- No data
- No status text

There is no 503 response reported "from the server" (from your interceptor) because the request was canceled prior to resolution.

For more information, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21916315/638329).