# Angular $http : setting a promise on the 'timeout' config

Tags: angularjs, promise

In the Angular [`$http` docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http), it mentions that you can set the 'timeout' config to either a number or a promise.

> **timeout** – {number|Promise} – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that
>   should abort the request when resolved.

But I am not sure how to make this work using a promise. how do i set a number and a promise ?
Basically I want to be able to know whether an http call (promise) errored due to a 'timeout' or something else. I need to be able to tell the difference.
Thanks for any help !!!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### This code is from [$httpBackend source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.13/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L131):

```
if (timeout > 0) {
  var timeoutId = $browserDefer(timeoutRequest, timeout);
} else if (timeout && timeout.then) {
  timeout.then(timeoutRequest);
}

function timeoutRequest() {
  status = ABORTED;
  jsonpDone && jsonpDone();
  xhr && xhr.abort();
}
```

`timeout.then(timeoutRequest)` means that when the promise is resolved (not rejected) timeoutRequest is invoked and xhr request is aborted.

---

If the request was timeout then `reject.status === 0` (**Note: in case of a network failure, then `reject.status` will also be equals to 0**), An example:

```
app.run(function($http, $q, $timeout){

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get('/path/to/api', { timeout: deferred.promise })
    .then(function(){
      // success handler
    },function(reject){
      // error handler            
      if(reject.status === 0) {
         // $http timeout
      } else {
         // response error status from server 
      }
    });

  $timeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve(); // this aborts the request!
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Also you can check for `statusText` value which would to be `"unknown"` https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.23/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L182 eg. `if (reject.status === 0 && reject.statusText === 'unknown') { ...` Should be careful thought, it's undocumented.

Comment: Actually `"unknown"` is present only for jsonp.

Comment: In 1.4.8 whether I resolve or reject the promise, the XHR is aborted. The problem though is that I can't pass any data to the rejection method, like my interceptor.

Comment: when i `deferred.reject('timeout')` from my function, I dont get timeout as response in my controller. Its always undefined. any idea why this happens?? I use  `deferred.reject();`  in my `$timeout`

Comment: @JayeshJain can you make a plnkr ?

Comment: @LeonardoDaCodinchi: Did you find the solution for your comment _when i deferred.reject('timeout') from my function, I dont get timeout as response in my controller?_ I'm searching for something very similar.

Comment: Perhaps counter-intuitive but the Promise you pass in as the timeout property must RESOLVE to successfully CANCEL the request.

Answer (score 2):

I had a sort a like question, you can check this link: [Angular 1.5 timeout using a HttpInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832962/angular-1-5-timeout-using-a-httpinterceptor) on how implement the timeout in an httpInterceptor. jsFiddle is included in the anwser. All credit go out to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959997/mita for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a embedded system and i was having hang outs from time to time since its a physical device so it stays turned on for days/months/years using $timeout fixed this behavior

Quick Example (timeout wrapper for http promises)

Module

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
```

Service

```
var yourServiceModule = myApp.service('YourService', function ($http) {
    this.your_method = function (a) { return a*a};
});
```

Controller

```
//just wrap your service,http call using $timeout
$timeout(function() {
    //vanilla service call
    YourService.your_method().then(
              function (response) {
                 //console.log("sync_with_cloud: "+ response);
                 $scope.check_cloud_port_statuses_progress=100;
                 //...
             },
              function(data) {
                  // Handle error here

                $rootScope.global_config_1 += "\nError(333): cant connect to cloud at "+Date.now();+"\n\n";
                $scope.check_cloud_port_statuses_progress = -1;
              }
    );

}, 8);
```