# Angular $http timeout returning undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm just testing the timeout functionality with Angular's $http module, however it keeps returning undefined as the response

It's fine if set up just like this, but if I tack on `.error(function)` instead of `.then(function)`, to the `$http` call, it throws an error trying to grab the data field from an undefined object

```
var timeout = $q.defer();

var config = {
        url: 'http://192.168.1.65:3000',
        timeout: timeout.promise,
        method: 'POST'
    };

    $http(config).then(function(res) {
        // This is always undefined when timeout occurs
        console.log(res);
    });

    $timeout(function() {
        console.log('resolving the promise to abort the http call. This works fine');
        timeout.resolve();
    }, 1000);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are not passing a value to your `resolve` call.

Comment: I don't believe thats the issue, I just tried as a sanity check and it didn't change anything...according to this other answer this should be all you need

Comment: Are you wanting to timeout your request or cancel it? I had to use something similar to this in my place of work and I don't think `timeout` accepts a promise. If you're looking to cancel your request, set `cancellationToken` to a promise. What other answer did you use?

Comment: @gfunk, when the request times out, it is a rejected promise - so you need `.catch`

Comment: oh sorry...this was the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21916315/3325262

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `$http` times-out, it returns a rejected promise that you can handle with `.catch`:

```
$http(config)
  .then(function(response){
  })
  .catch(function(error){
     // will fire when timed out
  })
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/v3DbLud3Ugf3VTiLPHGL?p=preview)

Off-topic: it's actually simpler to just use the promise generated by `$timeout`, without the need for `$q.defer`:

```
var timeout = $timeout(angular.noop, 1000);
$http.get(url, {timeout: timeout})
     .then(...)
     .catch(...)
```

**EDIT:**

In case there is an interceptor, then the timeout would result in `responseError`, and if defined, that interceptor essentially "handles" the error so it no longer becomes a rejected promise and the result is routed to `.then` - and if you do not return anything from the `responseError` function, the data passed to the `.then` handler is `undefined`. If you want to keep the rejection, you can do:

```
// inside http inteceptor
responseError: function(rejection){

  if (rejection.status === 0){ // if timeout
    return $q.reject({reason: "timeout"});
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: If this is true then why is his `console.log` printing undefined? :s

Comment: @DanPantry, if it's implemented as he states in the question, then it doesn't get there. Maybe something else is printing `"undefined"`

Comment: @NewDev you're right, there was an interceptor in the code that was catching the error and then returning undefined

Comment: @gfunk, it is quite an essential data point to the question :)