# Prevent AngularJS $http return on timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing custom `$http` service that looks something like this:

```
angular.factory('myHttp', function($http){
    var obj = {};

    obj.get = function(path) {
        return $http.get(path,{timeout: 5000}).error(function (result) {
                console.log("retrying");
                return obj.get(path);
        });
    }
});
```

The system works fine. It does return the data when success, and retrying when connection fail. However, I am facing problem that it will return to controller when the connection is timeout. How can I prevent it from returning and continue retrying?

Comment: Lookup the *retry* logic in your code and fix it there. Sorry can't give you any other advice without seeing your code. Retry is NOT a `$http` feature.

Comment: @Michael That's my code up there.... To use it, it can be use via `myHttp.get($scope.url).success(function(response) {});` Any advice to get it works?

Comment: @Michael It's there..... `return obj.get(path);` The logic works and it will retrying even when it is timeout.  The problem is when it is timeout, it will not wait for retrying and returning....

Comment: Al right.. yeah I was look somewhere else. You should use `.then(null, errorCallback)` instead of `error`. Using `then` you can return a promise, but not with using `error`. `error` is deprecated anyway and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot for your help. Using your suggestion method, I am able to do retrying. However, another problem appear. That is when using `myHttp.get('url').then(successCallback, errorCallback)`, even if the service return a fail connection, it will return to `successCallback` not `errorCallback`. How can I make it to `errorCallback`?

Comment: Please show the code you have now.

Comment: @Michael Here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/fx8wL4JvzJR9ZrkoJemD?p=preview

Comment: @Michael Do you have any idea to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$q.reject`. This will indicate that the error handler failed again and the result should populated to the parent error handler - NOT the success handler.

```
  obj.get = function(path) {
    return $http.get(path, {
      timeout: 5000
    }).then(null, function(result) {
      console.log("retrying");
      if (i < retry) {
        i += 1;
        return obj.get(path);
      } else {
        return $q.reject(result); // <-- use $q.reject
      }
    });
  }
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HDff1G77LzNw5WvQkaaA?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help.

Comment: I face one problem. How can I reset the counter `i` when the connection is success?

Comment: Put the counter `i` into the get function and wrap the $http request so you can do a retry without reset the counter. With this setup the counter `i` starts always at 0. No matter if the previous request was successful or not. See updated plunker

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But how can I access the updated plunker?

Comment: With the plunker link in this answer

Comment: Erm... But I can't find the updated plunker from it.

Comment: Yeah, but there is only 2 version in it. One was created by me, another one is modified by you. Can't find updated version in it.

Comment: Gosh! Just follow the plunker link in my answer. It will take you to the right version.

Comment: Could it be the cookies or session bring you to the right version? I can't see the right version there.....

Answer (score 0):

See the `reject.status` to determine the timeout

```
  $http.get('/path', { timeout: 5000 })
    .then(function(){

      // Your request served

    },function(reject){


      if(reject.status === 0) {

         // $http timeout

      } else {

         // response error 

      }
    });
```

Please see the following question for a good overview about handling timeout errors:

[Angular $http : setting a promise on the 'timeout' config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915834/angular-http-setting-a-promise-on-the-timeout-config)