# Abort $HTTP requests after some seconds and execute Error block forcefully in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am facing an issue in Ionic . I am trying to abort my $http post and get request after 20 seconds forcefully and want to execute the http call error block which says "server issue found" .Is there is any way to abort http call and execute its error block forcefully after some seconds in ionic or cordova .Thanks in AdvanceIs there is any kind of parameter passed in a call to abort it after that much of seconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular $http : setting a promise on the 'timeout' config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915834/angular-http-setting-a-promise-on-the-timeout-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax for timeout.

```
$http({
        method: POST,
        url: 'path/to/service',
        timeout: 5000
     }).success(function(data){
        // With the data succesfully returned, call our callback
        successFunc(data);
    }).error(function(){
        errorFunc("error");
    });
 }
});
```

Or modify the default timeout of http provider similar to following.

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;
}]);
```

Goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use timeout option in http request. If it reach the timeout limit, automatically it will execute the error block

```
 $http.get('path/to/service', {timeout: 5000});
```

Comment: what if the http request is the POST??

Comment: It applicable for POST also

Comment: Sorry Bro but this not worked in case of HTTP post request .I tried it but it is not going to error block .$http.post(url,{timeout:1000}, data, config)